# When i insert data into second textbox all the data inserted into first text boxes getting cleared

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Below code making textbox blank.As soon as control goes into 2 nd textbox ,first textbox getting blank.

```
{
    WebDriverWait wait34 = new WebDriverWait(d, 30);
    WebElement element34 = wait34.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("fisnInstrTypeDescriptionLabel")));
    element34.sendKeys(e.getCellData("ISIN", 19, i));

    WebDriverWait wait35 = new WebDriverWait(d, 30);
        WebElement element35 = wait35.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("fisnRestrictionsLabel")));
    element35.sendKeys(e.getCellData("ISIN", 20, i)); 

    d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@onclick='return submit_FISN();']")).click();
}
```

HTML Code for Both Elements

```
<input type="text" name="fisnInstrTypeDescriptionLabel" size="70" value="" onblur="setFISNComponent('fisnInstrTypeDescription');" id="fisnInstrTypeDescriptionLabel" style="text-align: right" class="textField ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="fisnRestrictionsLabel" size="70" value="" onblur="setFISNComponent('fisnRestrictions');" id="fisnRestrictionsLabel" style="text-align: right" class="textField ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: You don't have to use one wait for each locator. Only one is good for all. Instead of using wait34 and 35 and so on, just use wait.

Comment: @PrashantShinde Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: Actually i am automating the application ,Soi didn't have html code for same .

Comment: HTML code meaning from which you are getting the locators...your view source. You don't have that?

Comment: @eduPeeth   by using one wait for both locator,still error(getting blank textbox) persist.

Comment: Of course, that was just to make code better and not to fix the issue.

Comment: I don't think it is sending the values at all. The code is not right in the first place. How come you see value being typed in first text box?

Comment: @eduPeeth     values are fetching from excel(excel driven framework ) and which are properly inserting into 1st element but when control goes on 2nd element, 1st element  getting blank .

Comment: Then seems some issue with the locators that you are using.

Comment: At a guess, add sendKeys(ENTER) to element34 and check.

Comment: @PrashantShinde The first and the second both the fields have the attribute `onblur="setFISNComponent('fisnRestrictions');`. Update the question with the defination of `setFISNComponent()` and format of `fisnRestrictions`. Possibly something similar to `__doPostBack` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
{
WebDriverWait wait34 = new WebDriverWait(d, 30);
WebElement element34 = wait34.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("fisnInstrTypeDescriptionLabel")));  
element34.clear();
element34.click();
element34.sendKeys(e.getCellData("ISIN", 19, i));


WebElement element35 = wait35.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("fisnRestrictionsLabel"))); 
element35.clear();
element35.click();
element35.sendKeys(e.getCellData("ISIN", 20, i)); 



d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@onclick='return submit_FISN();']")).click();
}
```

Comment: Thanx for answer ,but its not working .still issue persist.

Comment: ...None of the error is display but the element get cleared.

Comment: if it gets clear , just provide something like :  `element34.sendKeys("Raw String");` and check whether it is taking the string value , then you can replace the same with `e.getCellData("ISIN", 19, i)` with some modification.

Comment: @cruisepandey......element34.sendKeys("Raw String");   still not working.its gets data cleared.